# R converting data frame into basket format

Tags: r, apriori, market-basket-analysis

i want to convert my data in basket format, my original data is

```
T_id  Transaction
10    A B C
20    A C D
30    A D E
40    B E F
50    B C D E F
```

i want to covert A B C as a separate items in transaction. b/c when i apply Apriori on my original data it takes A B C as a single item. i want to convert it like

```
T_id  Transaction
10    A,B,C
20    A,C,D
30    A,D,E
40    B,E,F
50    B,C,D,E,F
```

in order to convert A,B, and C as a individual items.

Comment: Convert A B C as a separate item?  Do you mean the `Transaction` column?  What is going on in the result?  Is that a list column?  Not sure what you mean by "individual items". Question need editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
data$Transaction = sapply(data$Transaction, function(x) gsub(" ", ",", x))
```